# R: How to subset a dataframe by another dataframe?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes `meth_df` and `class_df`. The column names of `meth_df` corresponds with the row names of `class_df`.

Original dimensions:

```
> dim(meth_df)
[1] 19143   865
> dim(class_df)
[1] 1146    3
```

`meth_df`

```
> dput(meth_df[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(`TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A` = c(0.611033076810465, 0.786837244239289, 
0.531054614303851, 0.711916183761331, 0.758443223998425, 0.936065885072034, 
0.610523796947026, 0.0360181294254416, 0.744836167093423, 0.825847426891416
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A` = c(0.468013052647261, 0.386177267500376, 
0.508623627469028, 0.403601275088479, 0.754642399207848, 0.905611840347474, 
0.513641472769712, 0.0369671655650615, 0.682167110003874, 0.91098916433555
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A` = c(0.593559707995411, 0.54983504208745, 
0.535207192925841, 0.613971903755576, 0.717278085189431, 0.914721280502537, 
0.618617844331457, 0.0380673866998774, 0.726852061395299, 0.903104180038181
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A` = c(0.638211007873003, 0.319561448644096, 
0.526699541432941, 0.450002172806716, 0.736440001203422, 0.937877051432322, 
0.580645503561395, 0.0347066379483443, 0.697023900940995, 0.944302291554549
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A` = c(0.603998109440889, 0.638039512259872, 
0.584328151056768, 0.594021097192165, 0.818583455926719, 0.923913298905444, 
0.598614422679214, 0.0377264836725614, 0.720058181085574, 0.875114543292475
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A` = c(0.430010814360424, 0.448824115778164, 
0.526908291064025, 0.518310265148905, 0.895158686818228, 0.887971782043668, 
0.607411484536684, 0.0362942319058598, 0.730871733359385, 0.916511320295343
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01A` = c(0.339041763485183, 0.17206807014635, 
0.509655632343845, 0.353815837324638, 0.774999215558209, 0.937536127356218, 
0.587036775760448, 0.0352676185475602, 0.722621569113857, 0.960178574261038
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J8-01A` = c(0.550222765165424, 0.454741999138921, 
0.357833139175962, 0.438336423352023, 0.686803252725261, 0.888503089392259, 
0.61396223864525, 0.0365946232140799, 0.70958690282282, 0.926998970607558
), `TCGA-2Z-A9J9-01A` = c(0.378560231419596, 0.296367959775822, 
0.552830632721739, 0.445042344000828, 0.825662959664014, 0.818693242846174, 
0.599475014121516, 0.0363543563119158, 0.691460153315781, 0.861781414445593
), `TCGA-2Z-A9JD-01A` = c(0.438988910905006, 0.381079255949129, 
0.534127218872017, 0.466668096811822, 0.831921748605766, 0.927149443646993, 
0.606125524091051, 0.0388050674426312, 0.709066294130399, 0.924064468064809
)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2M", "A2ML1", 
"A4GALT", "AAAS", "AACS", "AACSL"), class = "data.frame")
```

`class_df`

```
> dput(class_df[1:10,])
structure(list(survival = c("lts", "lts", "lts", "lts", "lts", 
"lts", "non-lts", "lts", "lts", "lts"), type = c("tumor", "tumor", 
"tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", 
"tumor"), subtype = c("kirp", "kirp", "kirp", "kirp", "kirp", 
"kirp", "kirp", "kirp", "kirp", "kirp")), row.names = c("TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J8-01A", "TCGA-2Z-A9J9-01A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JD-01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

My desired output should have `length(colnames(meth_df))` equal to `length(rownames(class_df))`.

First, I subset the `class_df`.

```
class_df <- class_df[!class_df["survival"]=="", ]
```

Second, I subset `meth_df` to keep only the columns that have column names that match the row names of `class_df`.

```
meth_df <- meth_df[colnames(meth_df) %in% rownames(class_df)]
```

Output dimensions:

```
dim(meth_df)
[1] 19143   660

> dim(class_df)
[1] 941   3
```

My question is: why are there less columns in `meth_df` output compared to rows in `class_df`?

I checked for duplicates:

```
> table(table(colnames(meth_df) ) > 1)

FALSE 
  660 
> table(table(rownames(class_df)) > 1)

FALSE 
  941
```

None are duplicates.

Comment: You haven't done anything to remove rows from `class_df` where the row name is not a column name in `meth_df`. So you have more rows in `class_df`. You seem to be assuming that filtering out rows where `survival == ""` will take care of that, but that's evidently not the case.

Comment: You could do `values_in_common = intersect(rownames(class_df), colnames(meth_df))` and then use `meth_df = meth_df[, values_in_common]` and `class_df = class_df[values_in_common, ]` to subset both of them down to the common values in a nice clear way.

Comment: Your example doesn't have any issue as you cited. `meth_df[, row.names(subset(class_df, nzchar(survival)))]`  gives the same number of columns

Comment: In your example, if you replace one of the `"lts"` values with an empty string `""`, then run your code, it appears to do exactly as you want. I'm not sure what could be going wrong, but if you wanted to upload the full tables you could run `saveRDS(meth_ds, "meth_ds.RDS")` (and the same for class_df), upload them to google drive or an equivalent, and provide the links.